# How to upgrade numpy on windows with out pip?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, numpy, pip

I need to upgrade to numpy 1.14.3 on a Windows computer. I tried using `pip install numpy --upgrade` in the command line and got `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` and the same message that pyton is not recognized when I try `python pip install numpy`.

Based on some googling it seems the issue is because python or pip are not added to the path. However, I am using a school computer and cannot access any advanced settings in order to add pip to path.

Is there an alternative command line upgrade method for numpy on windows?

Comment: If you cannot run python then what's the use of installing numpy?

Comment: @Goyo The weird part is I can run python in spyder just fine

Comment: Spyder knows where python is and that piece of data must be in some configuration dialog. Find it and use it to run python from the command line.

Comment: I think there is something wrong here. By installing python packages without knowing and understanding how python itself is installed you can easily make a mess of it. It looks like you have been provided with an environment that you are supposed to use as is. If you need this for school work you should probably ask somebody else to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have it installed, use Anaconda Navigator. Go to the Environments tab, and update whatever packages you need by filtering packages by upgradable! See screenshot below:

[image: Anaconda Navigator]

Since the asking user said he/she can’t upgrade to the version they need, try activating a new environment in the Anaconda Prompt, which should give you the latest version of numpy:

```
conda create -n TITLE_OF_ENVIRONMENT ipython-notebook numpy matplotlib pandas
```

*Update of what worked for the user*

Make sure that you run the `pip` command in the Anaconda Prompt and not in cmd! The `pip` command worked in the Anaconda Prompt, and the user was able to download the newest version of numpy.

Comment: So I found numpy in the anaconda navigator. When I right click a menu pops up with an option for Mark for Specific Installation. However, the newest option available for numpy is only 14.0 instead of 14.3

Comment: What if you establish a new environment in your Anaconda Prompt? `conda create -n TITLE_OF_ENVIRONMENT ipython-notebook numpy matplotlib pandas`

Comment: By making a new environment with numpy in the Anaconda Prompt, you should get the latest version of numpy available.

Comment: Are you using `pip` with cmd or Anaconda Prompt @user12120 ?

Comment: So I open a new terminal by clicking the triangle next to base(root) in navigator and selecting open in python. I typed the exact line you mentioned above and it returned a syntax error

Comment: Ah ha I did just open terminal this time and the line worked. Currently, waiting for it to download

Comment: Perfect! Glad it seems to be working at this point. I will update the answer above to reflect what worked for you.

Comment: Though when it asked if I wanted to install the latest version of conda with 14.2 of numpy when I do `import numpy print(numpy.version.version) ` it still prints 14.0. Is there a way to reload numpy in spyder?

Comment: Why do you need to install 1.14.3? Is there a functionality not working with what you currently have?

Comment: There's an astropy coordinate conversions issue that only happens on windows for numpy 14.0. It works fine on mac

Comment: Ah, I see. Try to open a notebook and see which version you of numpy you are running. If it’s anything > 14.0, try to run your coordinate conversion code to see if it works.

Comment: Still no luck. here is a link to my other astropy question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125864/how-to-upgrade-numpy-on-windows-with-out-pip/50126006?noredirect=1#comment87270801_50126006)